# PHP JSON Data Selection

Tags: php, json

How would I go about selecting the data of each title from the following JSON?
I have the JSON decoded, but I'm not sure how to select the part I want.

```
{
    "responseData": {
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "Justin Giesbrecht 749",
                "titleNoFormatting": "Justin Giesbrecht 749",
            },
            {
                "title": "Gopher dunes 09",
                "titleNoFormatting": "Gopher dunes 09",
            },
            {
                "title": "dirtbike Justin",
                "titleNoFormatting": "dirtbike Justin",
            },
            {
                "title": "A Warming",
                "titleNoFormatting": "A Warming",
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {
            "pages": [
                {
                    "start": "0",
                    "label": 1
                },
                {
                    "start": "4",
                    "label": 2
                }
            ],
            "estimatedResultCount": "6",
            "currentPageIndex": 0,
        }
    },
    "responseDetails": null,
    "responseStatus": 200
}
```

I thought it would be something like this, but I don't get anything:

```
echo "Response ". $jsonS->responseData->results[1]->title;
```

Comment: When you say you don't get anything, what do you mean? Do you see "Response" or not? Have you tried `var_dump($jsonS);`?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do see response, but I see nothing of the jsonS, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you've got the reading of the title part right, it's the JSON that is invalid.

Copying the JSON into a JSON validator/lint e.g. http://www.jsonlint.com/ will show that the you have additional , (commas) after the last object attribute in a few places (5 places to be exact, after each `'titleFormatting'` attribute and after `'currentPageIndex'`).

If you fix those errors and parse it using `json_decode` e.g.:

```
$jsonS = json_decode($json_text);
```

Then your own code:

```
echo "Response " . $jsonS->responseData->results[1]->title;
```

Will output the second (index 1 being the second index) results title

> Response Gopher dunes 09

Comment: +1: I answered that it was invalid, but your answer actually tells him *why*. Nice work!

Comment: Thank you, it was minor, but you were right! appreciate your time! Cheers. [answered]

Answer (score 0):

When you json_decode something it is converted to a regular PHP array, so you can reference it like $decodedObject["nodeName"].

Comment: As @Josh mentioned, this only works if you use `json_decode($json_data, true)`

Answer (score 0):

When I parse that JSON as you quoted it with PHP's `json_decode` method, it gives me NULL because PHP doesn't think it's valid JSON. Add a `var_dump($jsonS);` to see if this is happening to you as well. If it is, you may need to be sure your JSON is valid.

Here's what I did, for reference:

```
$json_data = <<<END_OF_JSON
{   
    "responseData": {        "results": [
            {
                "title": "Justin Giesbrecht 749",                "titleNoFormatting": "Justin Giesbrecht 749",
            },
            {
                "title": "Gopher dunes 09",
                "titleNoFormatting": "Gopher dunes 09",
            },
            {
                "title": "dirtbike Justin",
                "titleNoFormatting": "dirtbike Justin",
            },
            {
                "title": "A Warming",
                "titleNoFormatting": "A Warming",
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {
            "pages": [                {   
                    "start": "0",
                    "label": 1
                },
                {   
                    "start": "4",
                    "label": 2
                }
            ],
            "estimatedResultCount": "6",
            "currentPageIndex": 0,
        }
    },
    "responseDetails": null,
    "responseStatus": 200
}
END_OF_JSON;
$jsonS = json_decode($json_data);
var_dump($jsonS);
echo "Response ". $jsonS->responseData->results[1]->title;
```

And the output was:

> NULL Response

If you're using different JSON, please edit your question and share it. But if you're actually using the above, it's not valid...

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you are not allowed to leave trailing comma in array/object definition. So, when in PHP is perfectly valid to write:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,);
```

(note last comma), in JSON

```
a : [1,2,3,]
```

or

```
a : {x :'y',}
```

is invalid.